# Shape of a dot product between a numpy array and a constant of tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, dot-product

Unexpected array shape of the dot product result from a 2D numpy array and a constant tensor in tensorflow.

I am working on a problem that the input X needs to be preprocessed before feeding into my neural network model. The preprocess involves a lot of numpy array operations, and I found some unexpected results.

```
test1 = tf.constant(np.ones((3,1)),dtype=tf.float32)
test2 = np.ones((8,3,3))
test3 = np.dot(test2[1],test1)
test3.shape
```

I expect the result is (3,1), but the result is (3,3). In fact, no matter what the shape I put in the tf.constant, the result is always (3,3). Besides, I don't want to convert all my numpy array in the proprocess code to tensors. Any comments or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you look at the `test3` results?  Its `dtype`?  `shape` doesn't tell you everything.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. The test3 gives 3 by 3 numpy array, and each element is a tensor with shape (3,1). This looks like the elementwise product other than dot product, I want the result to be a 3 by 1 numpy array and each element is just a float. Any ideas?

Comment: `np.dot` tries to turn each argument into a numpy array (if it isn't already).  `np.array(test1)` is probably giving a 1 element object array, not a (3,1) numeric one.    You need to give `tf` control over this product, e.g. with `test1.dot(...)` or `test1@...`, or maybe a `tf.dot` if such exisits.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I really want to avoid using tf operations in my preprocess code. Is there any way to get (3,1) numeric result based on the above code?

Comment: In one way or other you need to convert this `tf` object into a numpy array.  That means you need to use some `tf` function or method.